# What are the ports used by Juju for its orchestration services?

Tags: juju

What  ports are required to be open on Ubuntu Cloud Guests running juju client instances?
As far as I understand, Zookeeper needs to communicate with all its nodes -- So that is  one requirement..
Anything else? Also what are the ports that are used by zookeeper? I need these so that I can put some security rules on my EC2 instances..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following ports are used by juju

- 22 - SSH
- 17017 - Juju API
- depending on the provider, you'll also want to open the StorageAPI port. (this is defined in your ~/.juju/environments.yaml for the provider)

However, when you're using a provider like EC2 - juju bootstrap will open these ports for you, so there's no real need to manually edit the EC2 security group rulesets.

Also, noteably - juju no longer uses zookeeper since it has moved from python to GoLang.

Comment: Thanx for the reply. So should I  assume that the open-port command may be a way to expose ports if I need to? I am asking these questions since I am authoring charms for my app specific deployments.

Comment: Also, it may be a nice feature if the open-ports can take an interface and ip-range/mask parameter to do the same giving some fine control to the charm author.

Comment: Since tunneling thru ssh is provided, that means I can tunnel through SSH to access my for e.g. DB instance directly..